# Find if portal server has ejb3

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, websphere-portal

What is the easiest way to check if my websphere portal server is having an EJB 3 container? The mtove is this. The portal invokes a remote EJB running on WAS. Now dependign on whether the portal has EJB 3 or not will determine if we need to generate EJB client stubs.
So what is the easiest way to find if the protal server has ejb3 compliance?

EDIT: Providing some more info if this helps:

```
$ ./WPVersionInfo.sh
WVER0010I: Copyright IBM Corporation 2002, 2008; All rights reserved.
WVER0011I: WebSphere Portal
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.10.1.1, dated 20091023_1701

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Portal Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time 2013-07-15T10:49:19-04:00

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer
Version Directory   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/version
DTD Directory       /opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/version/dtd
Log Directory       /opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/version/log
Backup Directory    /opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/version/backup
TMP Directory       /tmp

Installation Platform
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name           IBM WebSphere Portal
Version        6.1

Technology List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MP             installed
CFGFW          installed
FEAT615        installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name           IBM WebSphere Portal FeaturePack
Version        6.1.5.0
ID             FEAT615
Build Level    wp6103_201_01 2009-11-07
Build Date     11/07/2009

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name           IBM WebSphere Portal Configuration Framework
Version        6.1.0.3
ID             CFGFW
Build Level    wp6103_201_01 2009-11-07
Build Date     11/07/2009

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name           IBM WebSphere Portal MultiPlatform
Version        6.1.0.3
ID             MP
Build Level    wp6103_201_01 2009-11-07
Build Date     11/07/2009

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portal server itself won't support ejb3. If something supports ejb3 then it is the WebSphere Application Server underneath.

You should check the version from your WebSphere Application Server. As it is quite old I would guess you are using WAS 6.0 or 6.1. I doubt it would support EJB 3 out of the box. For WAS 6.1 however there is a [ejb 3feature pack](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247611.html).

If you use WAS 6.1 make sure that you migrate soon as it is running [out of support in September](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=C578916B44100K52-D404295E02966P57-B529169M78514S64).